# Generate a dynamic list in sony samrtwatch 2

Tags: android, listview, apple-push-notifications, android-notifications, sony-smartwatch

In my android application I need to develop a extension for Sony smart watch and I need to show a list.

This list needs to be refresh when i got push notification in my android device.

How can I add data dynamically and generate a list in smart watch. Currently I am able to add data as **push notification** comes in my device through notification API 
but I need to show it in a list view kind of widget. I also need to have my list visible after lights goes off like custom smart watch face does.

How can i achieve this??

Answer (score 3):

The Notification API will automatically display the notifications in a list format on the SW2 as you add them to the ContentProvider.  You shouldn't need to create any UI on your own if you build your extension as a Notification extension.

Comment: But how can i add data and show it using conrol api like we does with notification by adding data in content provider

Comment: here [link](http://android.brothersoft.com/smart_note_for_smartwatch_2-590289.html) is adding data to sw2 dynamically but without using notification

Comment: If you want to define your own UI then you will have to build it using the Control API and devise your own way to receive the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same problem, but I think here I can’t work with the notification api.
I have a list of items on the smartphone and I want to show the same list of items permanently on the SmartWatch.

The list on the smartphone will be refreshed by internet as soon as a second user who uses a similar application adds or deletes an item. In this case the list of items on the SmartWatch should be updated as well.

The items on the smartwatch can be droped by pressing a button on the SmartWatch display. Each item on the smartwatch has a buttom to delete it. In this case the list of items on the smartphone device should be refreshed, to show the same list of items.

I think I have to use the control api for this problem instead of the notification api because:

- The notification api can’t show the list of item permanently. The display turns back to the clock watch face after 2 seconds.
- The smartphone device can only add notifications on the smartwatch. In case an item has been deleted on the smartwatch, the notification api can’t delete it on the smartwatch.

Am I right to use the control api in this case?
Would you give me a hint how to realize the requiremtent?

Comment: Right, you will need to use the Control API as like you said, Notification API does not support those features above.